# undefined local variable or method on link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, link-to

Thats the link_to

```
<%= link_to('Dashboard', dashboard_index) do %>
  <i class="icon-play"></i>
<% end %>
```

Thats the corresponding `rake routes` entry.

```
dashboard_index GET    /dashboard/index(.:format)     dashboard#index
```

What could be wrong? Any suggestion or idea?

thanks in advance 
best regards
denym

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
<%= link_to(dashboard_index_path) do %>
  Dashboard
  <i class="icon-play"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For each entry in the `rake routes` output, two methods are created: `dashboard_index_path` which is `"/dashboard/index"`, and also `dashboard_index_url`, which will be something like `"http://mydomain.com/dashboard/index"`.